In Jenkins "Jira: Add related environment variables to build"
In Jenkins "Jira: Add related environment variables to build" this not able to fetch the issue key from the console log. In my console log i have commit messsage in which issue key is mentioned "Commit message: "BARBLD-4091: Jenkins connectivity". please help to solve this issue.
I have to update jira issue with customised comment. I am using freestyle job. and able to connect jira jenkins successfully.
